# call the methods from one activite to other( java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate())

Tags: android

I'm struck with some problem will calling the method from one activity to other......

I have a activity called Transaction2 in this activity,I have a method like getProposal().I need to call this method in to the other activity called PaymentDetails. I called the method like this : I import the activity(import com.Transaction2;) in to the paymentDetails and i create an object as

```
Transaction2 ts2 = new Transaction2();
```

and i call the method as `ts2.getProposal();`

when i called like this I am getting the exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually as i know, you cannot create a new activity by new. In android, Activity is suggest to designed as a standalone module, and the activity is created by android. If you want to communicate to other activities, you should use Intent to do this. And i strongly recommend you to put your application data out of your activity. Activity only take care of UI stuff.

Comment: thanku kevin and i have another problem that i need to send the request to the web service to the one method which is the response from the another method.....i am geting the response by getResponse()...It is returing like ().